# Python problem installing package for specific version "chess is not a package"

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

So, im trying with PUTTY in my server to install the chess python package.
The server has python 2.6 and python 3.4.
The chess pakcage only works with 3.4.

so to install it I run:

```
python3 -m pip install python-chess
```

Response:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python-chess in /home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (0.27.3)
```

Script Chess.py:

```
import chess
import chess.engine

fen = 'r2qkb1r/1p1bpp1p/p1n2p2/8/B1pP4/5N2/P1P2PPP/RN1QK2R w KQkq - 0 12'
board = chess.Board(fen)
handler = chess.uci.InfoHandler()
```

When i run the script with `python3 chess.py 2>&1`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chess.py", line 1, in <module>
    import chess
  File "/home/egqbe6ns/public_html/chess.py", line 2, in <module>
    import chess.engine
ImportError: No module named 'chess.engine'; 'chess' is not a package
```

Extended Info:

```
pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /home/egqbe6ns/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip (python 3.4)

python3 --version
Python 3.4.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have named your script `chess.py`. As, by default, the standard directories where modules would be searched for (`sys.path`) includes the current directory, `import chess` loads your script as the module. And obviously, it doesn't contain the submodule `engine`

Just rename the script to something else, remove the file `chess.pyc` if it exists and try again

Comment: great, but now I get this:   File "chess2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import chess
ImportError: bad magic number in 'chess': b'\xd1\xf2\r\n'

Comment: Did you delete the "chess.pyc" file?